# Pytest: print something in conftest.py without requiring "-s"

Tags: python, pytest, python-hypothesis

I am using environment variables to control some Hypothesis settings in `conftest.py`:

```py
test_max_examples = int(os.environ.get("TEST_MAX_EXAMPLES", "100").strip())
hypothesis.settings.register_profile(
    "dev",
    print_blob=True,
    max_examples=test_max_examples,
)

hypothesis.settings.load_profile("dev")
```

I would like to print these settings for the user's benefit, before running the tests.

However, my naive attempt failed, because Pytest captures output:

```py
print(hypothesis.settings.get_profile("dev"))
```

I am aware that the `capsys` fixture can be used inside tests to bypass output capturing, but I don't believe fixtures can be used at the top level of `conftest.py`.

Is there another solution to this? Or is this some kind of antipattern, and I'm not able to do this for a good reason?

I do *not* want to require the use of `-s` in Pytest unconditionally.

Answer (score 1):

The `print` should work for you if you use a `fixture` in `conftest.py` to set the `settings`. Use `scope='session', autouse=True` to run it once automatically

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='session', autouse=True)
def set_hypothesis():
    test_max_examples = int(os.environ.get("TEST_MAX_EXAMPLES", "100").strip())
    hypothesis.settings.register_profile(
        "dev",
        print_blob=True,
        max_examples=test_max_examples,
    )
    
    hypothesis.settings.load_profile("dev")
    print(hypothesis.settings.get_profile("dev"))
```

Comment: Sorry to un-accept the answer, but this didn't seem to do anything. I even tried using `capsys`, but I got an error because that fixture is function-scoped.

Comment: @shadowtalker it didn't print? or didn't run at all?

Comment: sorry, I wasn't clear. It didn't print anything.